# status-bydesign Tag

Tags: support, tags, meta

What exactly does the moderator-assigned  "status-bydesign" tag mean?  What other moderator only tags are there, and what are their meanings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Status-bydesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) is the response to a bug/feature request stating that this is the intended behavior.

[Status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) means the feature/bug fix has been implemented.

[Status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) means the feature request is "rejected" and will not be implemented.

[Status-norepro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-norepro) means a bug cannot be duplicated

[Status-planned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned) is a feature that is being planned.

[Status-review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review) is a bug/feature being reviewed.

[Status-reproduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) is a bug that has been successfully reproduced.

I'm not sure what [status-deffered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred) is intended to mean.

I believe there is also a status-accepted (though there are none currently) which would be when a feature request has been accepted, but has not been completed yet.

Comment: As per the question, what other moderator tags are there?

Answer (score 4):

Status-bydesign: The problem someone is complaining about is there by design.

Status-completed: The request has been taken care of.

Status-declined: The request will not be implemented.

Status-norepro: We are unable to reproduce the bug.

Status-deferred: We are planning to look at this issue in the future.

Status-planned: We are have already planned a fix.

Status-review: We are reviewing your request.

Status-reproduced: We've reproduced your bug, and are trying to figure it out.