# Change in post title for the duplicate post title says 'How does Meta Stack Overflow work?'

Tags: support, migration, meta

Today when searching for some post I see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7677/status-tags-moderator-only) post, it was a duplicate of this [community wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work).

The community wiki post's previous title was **How does Meta Stack Overflow work?**, but later it changed to **How does Meta Stack Exchange work?**

After the migration all the posts should define about the MSE only not MSO, so I made a [suggested an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44250) and it was approved. In few other posts also the same change need to apply. I don't want to make the same edit in all those posts and increase the review queue count and waste their time too.

Can the moderators or the edit questions and answers privileges correct the content for the below posts?

[Does MSE provide which bugs are being solved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125265/does-mso-provide-which-bugs-are-being-solved)

[status-bydesign Tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/status-bydesign-tag)

[What are all the moderator-only tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144954/what-are-all-the-moderatory-only-tags)

[Why are some tags in a different color?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136426/why-some-tags-are-in-different-color)

[do downvotes on meta indicate disagreement with the question's premise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112396/do-downvotes-on-meta-indicate-disagreement-with-the-questions-premise)

Comment: It's the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually should happen is that they are reopened and closed as duplicate again. Then the banner can be removed from the body. The reason for that is the automatically inserted duplicate banned that used to be added to (alleged) duplicates.

Since quite some years now the banned is separated from the actual body, so the question title will be updated automatically too when it changes.

---

All done now.